# No internet connection, can't flush dns

Tags: windows, networking, dns, internet, dns-cache

I can't connect to the internet, I tried these commands, but none of them are working..
What's weird, is that when I wait around 10 minutes, the internet hops back, but the commands are still not working..

Commands I tried to fix this issue:

```
netsh int ip reset reset.log
netsh advfirewall reset
ipconfig /flushdns # Stuck at "Windows IP Configuration"
ipconfig /registerdns
route /f
```

Nothing worked for me..

> Commands

```
C:\Windows\System32>ipconfig /flushdns

Windows IP Configuration

^C # Stays still on the Windows IP Configuration
```

```
C:\Windows\System32>net stop dnscache
The service is not responding to the control function.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2186.
```

As the last effort I tried disabling the dnscache service (Using regedit). BOOM! Everything started working like a charm.

I don't know what to do now.. I don't want to be without the dnscache service..

Comment: Try a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation link. Use the option to Keep Everything

Comment: You missed  `netsh winsock reset catalog`. Do this first and then the other commands you tried.

Comment: Still not doing anything. I didn't want to reinstall the entire OS, I already tried upgrading to win 11, hoping it would fix, but no.. I'll try the Microsoft media creation link, hopefully it will work.

Comment: Still the same issue.. Is it possible to reset entire windows including config without losing files?